# SFMC Reports on new records in data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

Is there a report for new records in a data extension within a time increment?

I initially thought it would be this: `Sendable Data Extension Performance Over Time` but I'm not showing results in the Analytics Builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing out of box.

You could add a 'DateAdded' field to your DE and default it with a Date. 
You could then build your own report using an SQL Query.

Comment: Can that SQL query generate a daily email?

Comment: The sql will output a result to a data extension. You can send an email to the results of the data extension. If you want to extract an email the results, then you could set up a Data Extenion Extract (Automation) to extract the result and place on FTP. It would take some scripting to get the report attached to an email though. You could build a dashboard in Marketing Cloud using the data in the DE - your 'dashboard could be built in a Cloud Page.